# How can I tell Cypress to hide Chrome when running from the command line?

Tags: cypress

### Problem

I want to be able to run my tests in terminal, but all my tests fail due to Cypress using Electron as the default browser and I want it to utilize Chrome, but without having to specify it in the command line.

### Current Outcome

I know I can use the command `npx cypress run --browser chrome` to tell Cypress to use Chrome instead. However, it opens the browser AND runs it in command line.

### Expected Outcome

Ideally it would only require me to run `npx cypress run` and this would **only** run in the command line using Chrome.

### Summary

Is there a way to set the default browser to Chrome instead of Electron so I wouldn't need to specify which browser to use?

Is there something to add to the `package.json` file to set the default browser to Chrome or a line to inject somewhere? I checked the docs and I couldn't really find anything other than the `--browser` command.

### ** Cypress Github Open Issue **

Here is the link to the open issue on their github regarding a headless chrome and also to change the default for `cypress run`

[Support chrome headless and change defaults for cypress run](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/832)

### Photo for the debugger

Sorry for the terrible scribbles...I am under an NDA so had to go back and scratch out all the path names for my project as well as my last name.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Cypress 3.8.1+ allows you to pass `--headless` to `cypress run` to make Chrome invisible on any operating system by using Chrome headless:

`cypress run --headless --browser chrome`

---

## **Outdated answer below:**

> There is not currently a way to hide Chrome in `run` mode on macOS or
>   Windows.
>
> We'd like to support it, but we'd have to find some kind of workaround
>   for `xvfb` not being available. We can't use `google-chrome
>   --headless` either because it won't allow us to install the Cypress extension.
>
> ---
>
> **The advice below will only work for Linux.**
>
> `npx cypress run --browser chrome` is the correct way to do what
>   you're trying to do.
>
> If you are on Linux, you can make it run Chrome in a virtual
>   framebuffer (so it will be hidden from you) by blanking out the
>   `DISPLAY` env variable:
>
> `DISPLAY= npx cypress run --browser chrome`
>
> ---
>
> Technical explanation:
>
> 1. Cypress does not support running in "headless Chrome" - headless Chrome was not around when Cypress was first written
> 2. So, when Cypress is running in Chrome in CI, it uses `xvfb` to create an X virtual framebuffer, then it uses the `DISPLAY` variable
>      to tell Chrome to run in the `xvfb`
> 3. However, if you have `DISPLAY` set (by default, it is set on Linux if you have a display manager), it will use that `DISPLAY` instead -
>      this is why it appears even though you're doing `cypress run`.
> 4. Adding `DISPLAY=` before the command nulls out `DISPLAY`, which means that Cypress will spawn `xvfb` and run it inside of there
>      instead.

Comment: So i tried the ```DISPLAY= npx cypress run --browser chrome``` command and it still opened a chrome window and I dont want it to :(

Comment: @HyeEun hmm, that shouldn't be happening. Can you run with debug logs and pastebin them to me? `DEBUG=cypress:xvfb,cypress:cli DISPLAY= npx cypress run --browser chrome` And what OS are you working on?

Comment: I just updated the post with the photo of my terminal.

Comment: also im working in mojave and my app needs to run with chrome 63+

Comment: It turns out that my advice is only correct for Linux. There is not currently a way for you to hide Chrome in run-mode on OS X. If you'd like, you can make a feature request: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/new/choose

Comment: gotcha I see. I will definitely make that feature request. And, I thank you for the help and suggestions. Hopefully, if anything, someone else will find help in this! :D

Comment: I see `could not find CRI target` when trying to run `cypress run --headless --browser chrome` on 3.8.2. I found this...
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6053

Comment: TIP: Add this line to package.json scripts -> `"e2e:ci": "cypress run --headless --browser chrome"` and then you can just run `yarn e2e:ci`